# How to make sure android tts synthesizes a file?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using the Android TTS function synthesizeToFile() to create certain words/letters.
The problem is it works fine for larger files but for single character words it **sometimes** creates a 0 byte file.

Eg

```
    tts.synthesizeToFile("a", myHashRender,"/location/a.wav");
```

or

```
    tts.synthesizeToFile("c", myHashRender,"/location/c.wav");
```

I tried to pad it with spaces i.e. generate "a .wav" from "a " but this does not work either. I need a way to consistently generate these files successfully or using the listener synthesize them again onError().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TTS doesn't pronounce single letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716851/android-tts-doesnt-pronounce-single-letter)

Comment: That question is about the speak() method, mine is about the synthesize() method. Both do completely different things though they do have the same listener.

Comment: If you read it carefully and think a little bit you'll get the insight of the problem.